# Generate an error message for an invalid number of inputs on c++ cin

Tags: c++, cin

I'm using the following code:

```
string a, b, c;
cin >> a >> b >> c;
```

Explained: if a user inputs e.g. `"hello new world hi"`
then the mapping is `a='hello'`, `b='new'` and `c='world'`. The `"hi"` will be ignored - and that's the problem!

What i want is, that in case of a wrong number of arguments (more or less than 3), the user should be forced to input again (maybe by an error message).

Comment: Read the whole line. Extract your three words. Check if there's more available. [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) and [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) are very useful for this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I think I have to specify my question more. I'm aware of your way but I just curious just if is there any function or way to find error of invalid number of input using 'only' cin like above.

Comment: From what you write it seems that you want to check if there are more characters available in the input stream. I don't think there is a convenient and easy way to do it.

Comment: No there's really no (nice) way of using the formatted input operators directly on `std::cin` to see if you have read a full line or not. Unless you enable [`std::noskipws`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) and read character by character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, if you type in 4 words then the last word will exist somewhere on your machine(maybe on keyboard buffer). Thus, if you use `cin` to type value for another variable, the last word will be assign to the variable. So to check if user has typed error or not, you can do as following:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   string a, b, c;
   cin >> a >> b >> c;

   string check="";
   getline(cin, check);
   if (check != "")
   {
      cout << "input error,try again!";
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getline(cin, stringName)`
After the input iterate through string check the index of spaces, and then split it into whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You even don't need to declare three string to store. You can use std::getline.

```
 std::string a;//,b,c; 
 std::getline(std::cin,a); //<< b << c; 
 std::cout <<a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read whole line with std::getline, and then separate line by spaces. For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
// some code...
    std::string text;
    std::getline(std::cin, text);
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    int wordCount = 0;
    while (auto space = text.find_first_of(' '))
    {
        wordCount++;
        if (wordCount > 3)
        {
            std::cout << "Max 3 words!" << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        words.push_back(text.substr(0, space));
        text = text.substr(space + 1);  
    }
```

This way you will have max 3 words in vector `words`, you can get them by calling `words[0]` for first, etc. At 4th read word error is printed and `while` loop stops.